# Posting a form of variable length per jquery AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, forms

I have a form where the user can add any number of input fields.
those are sent to a .php which returns a result out of those submitted.
that means I can't know the length of the $_POST beforehand (and I don't want to).

Everything I found so far works with manually entering the fields into the ajax request

```
// Get some values from elements on the page:
var $form = $( this ),
term = $form.find( "input[name='s']" ).val(),
url = $form.attr( "action" );
```

(from the jQuery api)
but that would only work if I know how many fields there would be.
I just want all the fields (no matter how much there were added) to be posted..

is it possible to loop through all fields?
or to just send the normal $_POST as it would be posted without ajax?

Comment: make it easy on yourself and use **[serialize()](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use jQuery's [.serializeArray()](http://api.jquery.com/serializeArray/) or [.serialize()](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/) depending on how your PHP expects the data.

The difference is that .serializeArray() creates a JSON array while .serialize() creates standard URL-encoded key/value pairs.

Comment: it really was that simple. php script just took it as if it would have been posted normally. thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you want to send it via AJAX and you are using jquery `.serialize()` will make it much easier. You can put all of the inputs inside a form then use `$(form).serialize()` as the data.

Here is the jquery documentation for `.serialize()`

http://api.jquery.com/serialize/

Answer (score 0):

`var values = {};
$.each($('#myForm').serializeArray(), function(i, field) {
    values[field.name] = field.value;
});`

This way your value array will have all the fields in your form 'myForm'